# Auto generate swagger schema definitions

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm automatically generating my api documentation using the swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc libraries. Follow swagger setup code in app.js:

```
const swaggerJsDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      title: 'My API',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
    servers: ['http://localhost:8000'],
  },
  apis: ['./routes/*.js'],
};
const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);

app.use('/api-docs',
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs),
);
```

In routes files is like that

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /user/get/all:
 *  get:
 *   summary: Get all users
 *   responses:
 *    '200':
 *     description: successful operation
 */
```

I'm looking for a way to automatically generate the schema definitions of my models. If I were generating the swagger documentation with a json, I would do it like this:

```
"definitions": {
  "ApiResponse": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "code": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "Category": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int64"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "xml": {
      "name": "Category"
    }
  },
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do to auto generate these schema definitions?

Comment: if by "Schemas" and "Models" you refer to the `mongoose` ones, I'd suggest you take a look at the `mongoose-to-swagger` package.